# Removing lines with less than 10 characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I work under Windows, I'm trying to clean a text I'd like to study, what's the right regex in Notepad++ to remove lines which are <= 10-character-sized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search:

```
^.{0,9}((\r?\n)|$)
```

Replace with a blank (ie nothing)

Comment: Also `\r\n` assumes that the file itself has windows line-endings as well.

Comment: This won't work on the very last line of a file if it doesn't end in a line break.

Comment: Maybe rather something like `...$[\r\n]*`. Or what HamZa said.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these replies... apparently Notepad++ does not acknowledge the curly brackets so one as to go for something like: ^..?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?$  (I guess better go Linux and use the command line... thanks, guys!

Comment: I take it back, have just updated my Notepad++, curly brackets awe well respected.

Answer (score 0):

**Step.1)** Replace all the lines containing **less than or equal to 10 chars** with empty string.
`^.{0,10}$`
[image]

**Step.2)** Now you have lots of empty lines. So, remove empty lines:
`Remove Empty Lines`
**"Edit" > "Line Operations" > "Remove Empty Lines"**

Comment: Less than 10 doesn't include 10. We have to remove from 0 upto 9 character long.

Comment: Thanks @Toto for pointing the boundary case.
Corrected the post.